# List from algebraic expression?

Tags: list-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation

Consider an algebraic expression

```
exp = a x^2 -b x +c
```

I want to create a list from its element:

```
list = {a x^2,  -b x, c}
```

Is there any inbuilt command in Mathematica for this?

If not, is there any command to count the number of terms in an algebraic expression?

Comment: Please post code as code, not LaTeX, to make it copyable. Simply use `List @@ exp` (look up `Apply`) or use `CoefficientList`

Comment: @ChandanSharma: Another approach: eq = a x^2 - b x + c; Reverse[Table[Extract[i][eq], {i, 1, Length[eq]}]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining the two answers in the comments:

```
exp = a x^2 - b x + c
Reverse[List @@ exp]
```

(Please give credit in the comments rather than here.)